# Fetching results as LinkedHashSet or Set with @Query() or entityManager.getResultList() in Hibernate and JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I wonder if it is possible to do getResultList() #getResultSet() or @Query() with return type of Set or LinkedHashSet. My db is designed to not have any duplicate row in a table so I thought using Set and LinkedHashSet would be the better approach for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the API doesn't provide any methods that return Sets. The only you could do would be to get the result as a List and then create the Set yourself.

Comment: i thought they made set the standard for jpa. Do you know if it is possible for me to contact the people who are maintaining jpa to ask?

Comment: Sure, you can reach out to them here: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Here is a method I just created and tested:

```
@Query(value = "FROM CountryCode cc WHERE cc.id < 5")
Set<CountryCode> test();
```

Comment: This is a Spring Data JPA feature and not a Hibernate or JPA feature. 
Spring Data JPA uses the API defined by the JPA specification and implemented by Hibernate. That API returns a List. 
You or any framework that you use, can, of course, map this List to a Set. But this is a postprocessing step that creates an additional Set.